# Produce specific effect with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am using Photoshop CC 19.1.2. and I have the following problem:

I want to add to a more or less random picture after a blur (gaussian or maybe field blur) the following effect:

[image]

As you can see, it gives it a touch of blurred shower window (like if you dont have a curtain or a transparent glass wall, but one with some kind of blinding pattern). It may be some kind of noise/selective emboss effect with highlights and shadows.

How would you proceed?

Answer (score 4):

It is merely Filter > Filter Gallery > Distort > Glass.

Note you have to use the **Filter Gallery**. You can no longer get to the "Glass" filter without using the gallery it seems.

Comment: Actually you can add the glass filter and others back in the preferences. Click Edit > Preferences > Plug-ins, then choose the option "show all filter gallery groups and  names". That'll put them back in the filter menu.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr I thought there was some setting somewhere for that, but wasn't certain.

Comment: I have no idea why Adobe felt the need to disable those filters from appearing in the filters menu. It's another one of those pointless changes that Adobe makes from time to time.